# Why does Android phones need JAVA?

Tags: samsung, java

Im going to buy a [Samsung A310F Galaxy A3](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a3_(2016)-7791.php). But I noticed one thing.

**FEATURES

Java    No**

This samsung smart phone doesnt have Java in it. So the main my question would be: is it really bad? And why does Android smart phone need Java? Is it a big disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you wont be able to play games from your browser who are written in Java (Java 2 ME platform). Some of the browser games are written on that particular platform, so you will not be able to play them.

Answer (score 0):

As @FiN said, that indication doesn't mean that this phone doesn't run Java at all (in fact, many apps and many parts of the Android system are written in Java) but it means that you can't run Java ME applets. This is not a bad thing because Java ME is almost nowhere on smartphones today, so you won't miss anything.